# How to add Distinct in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

In my database I have a Test table, with columns: testName, testType 
there are 2 different tests with the same type I.e "SUN", so I want only one of them for which I use Distinct in my hibernate / criteria as below, but it still giving me both the types with the same name as "sun".

```
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Test.class);

    final ResultTransformer trans = new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer();
    crit.setResultTransformer(trans);
    List rsList = trans.transformList(crit.list());
```

Any idea what could be the reason, or any other way of filtering duplicates.

Answer (score 31):

Use Projections.distinct.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Test.class).setProjection(
    Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("type"), "type") )
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YourBean.class)); 

List lst = crit.list();
```

where YourBean.class has a property "type". The returned list will be `List<YourBean>`.

Comment: thanks , now its giving the correct result , but its in the form of a string after this statement , whereas i want the complete object and return the complete object ,I want the testname value as well, how can i get that

Comment: @Dandy, nice answer provided but I'm still getting a problem. The bean I'm getting contains only "type". Other properties of Test class are having null or 0 value. How can I get those values along with the unique type restriction.

Comment: Isn't there a bracket missing?

Comment: For me the returned is `List<typeOf"type"Field>`.

Answer (score 26):

Try to use :

```
cr.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

It work perfectly for me

Comment: Can you add more information on why it worked for you?

Comment: Great answer, worked for my case as well in only 1 additional line (instead of 10...)

Comment: This is pretty limited solution. When using ResultTransformer, hibernate does not include DISTINCT in SQL query, so we fall in troubles with paging (limit/offset)

Comment: In my case, when I need to fetch details in outer join, it works perfect. Hibernate otherwise for each detail multiply the **identical** objects in the result set. To reduce those unexpectable duplicities it works very well. Of course, for paging, this method is not useful.

Comment: Muhammad Abdul-Rahim, this Distinct is done not on the level of database select - thi is the same without distinct, but on the level of fetched and formed collection of result set of objects in memory. Simply, the identical multiply objects (really identical - there objectid1 == objectid2...) are shrinked into the one.

Answer (score 5):

I finally have found out to get values of other columns:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
ProjectionList projectionList2 = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList2.add(Projections.distinct(projectionList.add(Projections.property("distinctColumn"), "distinctColumn")));
projectionList2.add(Projections.property("col1"), "col1");
projectionList2.add(Projections.property("col2"), "col2");
criteria.setProjection(projectionList2);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class)); 
List list = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use :

```
Criteria criteria = 
    session.createCriteria(Test.class).setProjection(
        Projections.distinct(Projections.property("testType")));
List<Test> rsList = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and ended up solving using the Group By projection and then adding in all the columns I needed.  For example

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Class.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("Col1"), "Col1")
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("Col2"), "Col2"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.class));
List list =  query.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`, like this:

```java
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
List list = crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Projections provide the result of the marked properties only. but, it creates problem for the child entities. See my post for the real problem I faced it.

[Hibernate: Parent and Child relationship data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295325/hibernate-parent-and-child-relationship-data-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

It uses default hashcodes to find matches in results.

Thanks.