# Hibernate Criteria Query to get specific columns result

Tags: hibernate, criteria

i am try to get single column result  using Criteria  but i did not get the prefect output for that

```
Criteria criteria =  session.createCriteria(GroupName.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.property("groupName"));
        criteria.createAlias("gcmUsers", "user").setResultTransformer(
                Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.clientName", userName));
        groupNames=criteria.list();

 i am getting this output :

Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, twiter_grp


but my actual output is :
Default, twiter_grp,friends
```

Comment: So ultimately you're facing 2 problems: 1. you're not getting distinct result & 2. you're not getting `friends` in output. Right?

Comment: yes i am facing 2 problems.

Comment: Can you show tables with data?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731723/how-to-add-distinct-in-hibernate-criteria/15333002#15333002

Comment: gcmUserstable and GroupName having many to many relationship . and user name is admin and data for group table is Default, twiter_grp,friendsgroup names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Projections.distinct method

```
Criteria criteria =  session.createCriteria(GroupName.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("groupName")));
        criteria.createAlias("gcmUsers", "user").setResultTransformer(
                Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.clientName", userName));
        groupNames=criteria.list();
```

[More about projections distinct method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#distinct%28org.hibernate.criterion.Projection%29)