# CriteriaQuery with One-to-Many and Many-to-One Relationships

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have 3 tables in question: PrblFldr --> PrblFldrAtrbtVal --> PrblTmpltAtrbt. The relationships between these are "one-to-many" and "many-to-one", respectively.

I am using `CriteriaBuilder` to perform a search on `PrblFldr` objects. I need to search by the values of each `PrblFldrAtrbtVal` that is associated with the `PrblFldr`. The query parameters' keys are the unique PKs that associate each `PrblFldrAtrbtVal` with a `PrblTmpltAtrbt`; the value of the parameter is what to search for in the `PrblFldrAtrbtVal`'s value.

Here's my code so far (**edited**):

```
@GET
@Path("/folders/search")
public Response searchFolders(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PrblFldr> cq = cb.createQuery(PrblFldr.class);
    Root<PrblFldr> folder = cq.from(PrblFldr.class);
    Join<PrblFldr, PrblFldrAtrbtVal> attributes = folder.join("prblFldrAtrbtVals");
    Join<PrblFldrAtrbtVal, PrblTmpltAtrbt> attributeTemplates = attributes.join("prblTmpltAtrbt");

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

    for (String key: queryParams.keySet()) {
        String value = queryParams.getFirst(key).replaceAll("_", "\\\\_");

        predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(attributeTemplates.<String>get("tmpltAtrbtSeqId"), key),
                cb.like(attributes.<String>get("fldrAtrbtVal"), "%" + value + "%", '\\')));
    }

    cq.distinct(true).select(folder).where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
    List<PrblFldr> results = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(results), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

**EDITED:** It is currently working if I only pass in one key/value pair to search for. If I pass in more than one `PrblFldrAtrbtVal` to search for, a blank result set is returned, despite the fact that one or more `PrblFldr` objects should be matched by the specified `PrblFldrAtrbtVal` objects.

I think it has something to do with the `cb.and()` statement in the `cq.where()` clause. I do want an 'AND', but why is returning back no results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is returning an empty list because the predicates are added with an 'AND'. 
i.e., the query being generated is something like;

```
tmpltAtrbtSeqId = '1' AND fldrAtrbtVal like '%a%'
AND tmpltAtrbtSeqId = '2' AND fldrAtrbtVal like '%b%'
AND tmpltAtrbtSeqId = '3' AND fldrAtrbtVal like '%c%'
```

when you pass in multiple key/value pairs.

You need to add a 'OR' clause in the for loop.

Comment: Oh I see, but wouldn't I want the 'OR' clause to be, instead, on the predicates when they are converted to an array? I do want the two statements in the for-loop to be AND'ed because they ensure the value and the `tmpltAtrbtSeqId` match the correct `PrblFldrAtrbtVal`.

Comment: I have edited my original post after trying your suggestion. Please see the new issue.

Comment: I think you need to add a 'DISTINCT' to the query. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731723/how-to-add-distinct-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Yep, you're right. One more thing (sorry!), it looks like (because the attributes are OR'ed together) that I'm actually not getting the result set I want; I actually do want the attributes to be AND'ed together so if the user specifies more than 1 attribute, it should look for folders that contain ALL of the attributes specified. Again, changing it to be 'AND' will return a blank result set.

Comment: Oh Ok. We had such a situation in our project. What you need is an intersection query. You will need to get list of PrblFldrAtrbtVal that match the first key, a list of PrblFldrAtrbtVal that match the second key, a list of PrblFldrAtrbtVal that match the third key (and so on) and take an intersection of these. Not sure how this will be done using CriteriaBuilder. If you give me the table definitions, i might be able to give you a jpa query.

Comment: You might have to add a subquery for each key/value pair.

Comment: There has to be an easier way... I saw something that might work involving `group by` and `having` clauses, but I don't know how that would be applied to this situation.

Comment: Well, if you want to use group by and having then, you probably will have to use 'OR' without 'DISTINCT', then do a count of PrblFldr grouping by the PrblFldr (or its id), adding a 'HAVING' clause with  count(PrblFldr) = '<number of key/value pairs>'. So, you will get PrblFldr records only if they occur as many times as there are key/value pairs.

Comment: In SQL terms you want something similar to; SELECT PrblFldr, count(PrblFldr) from PrblFldr join PrblFldrAtrbtVal join PrblTmpltAtrbt where (tmpltAtrbtSeqId = 'x' and fldrAtrbtVal like '%y%') or (tmpltAtrbtSeqId = 'x1' and fldrAtrbtVal like '%y1%') group by PrblFldr having count(PrblFldr) = '<number of key/value pairs>'.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that with no luck. It seems like the groupBy/having statement had no effect and the result set was as if I OR'ed everything together without the distinct clause, leaving me with duplicates and OR'ed clauses instead of AND'ed.

Comment: Is the grouping on the id of PrblFldr?

Comment: For the time being, I followed your original suggestion of matching each PrblFldrAtrbtVal separately and taking the intersection of this. This works very well, though performance needs optimized. I'll tackle that bear once I get all this working! Thanks for your help!