# Criteria API and unique results

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

The next code results with all rows where `ispassed=true`:

```
Criteria crit = hSession.createCriteria(ResultTable.class);
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("ispassed", true));
crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
total = (long) crit.uniqueResult();
```

But 'ResultTable' table contains also `user_id` column and there can be rows like:

```
-ispassed              -user_id
true                    1
true                    1
true                    2
true                    3
true                    4
```

So how can I get only rows where `user_id` is unique? 
So that the result must be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to get the number of rows whose `isPassed` status is true and want to consider only one such record per user. If so, you can try:

```
Criteria crit = hSession.createCriteria(ResultTable.class);
crit.add( Restrictions.eq("ispassed", true));
crit.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("userId"));
total = crit.list().size();
```

**NOTE:** Assuming `user_id` is mapped as `userId` field in your `ResultTable` entity.

Comment: @rozerro We can further simplify it. Updated the answer. You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Projections.distinct() should get only distinct combinations.

Look here for some examples:
[How to add Distinct in Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731723/how-to-add-distinct-in-hibernate-criteria)