# Hibernate Criteria Returning Set

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I Have a class which contains a Set of objects.
Using Hibernate Criteria, how can I return that Set of objects, as opposed to the objects of the class on which the query is being called?

In standard HQL, I'm using the following : `select o.routes from Operator o where o.name = :diamond`, where routes is the set of objects I wish to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this
[How to add Distinct in Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731723/how-to-add-distinct-in-hibernate-criteria)
where in you are setting the projection to a specific object. you can also convert it to the class of that object.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: And what would I be setting the object to? Route or Set<Route>?

Comment: it would be List<Route> but the list will have distinct element.

Comment: It should be something like this

List<Route> list = session.createCriteria(Operation.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("name","variable"))                 
.setProjection(
    Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("route"), "route") )
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Route.class))
.list();